# Brining a laptop for personal use to UK from outside EU, If I include it when applying for Tor1, should I decleare my laptop at customs?

Tags: united-kingdom

Next march I am going to UK as immigrant, of course I will bring my laptop(bought a few months ago) with me, the purchased price was over 390GBP. I will also include it when applying for Tor1. Should I use 'Red Channel' to declare on arrival?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [government's website](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/transfer-of-residence-to-great-britain) the safest thing is to go through the red route, as you'll be travelling with belongings worth more than £390. If you already filled in your Tor1, then make sure you show it if asked.

> ## How to go through customs
>
> ### What to do when you arrive at customs
>
> In most cases, you’ll be able to go through the green ‘nothing to
> declare’ channel.
>
> You **must go to the red point or** into the red channel to declare the
> following:
>
> - prohibited or restricted goods
> - goods for sale
> - **belongings or vehicles which need to be declared in order to be considered for relief from duty and tax**
>
> **If you’re not sure what to do, declare your goods through the red
> point or red channel.**
>
> ### How to declare goods if they’re travelling with
> you
>
> Tell the officer what goods you’ve brought with you. It may help if
> you’ve a written list of the goods concerned, but the officer may
> still want to question you, examine your luggage or ask you to make a
> written declaration. **If you have prior approval, evidence of this
> should be provided.**

Note that there's a [separate guidance](https://www.mta.org.uk/resources/travelling-laptop-and-personal-effects) if you're travelling between the UK and EU, where the limit is £1500 instead of £390. This doesn't apply to you as you're travelling from outside the EU.